# Encoding superscript in oracle database

Tags: oracle

I need to insert text into the table that contains superscripts. Is there a way to do this in Oracle database? I tried to use ASCII encoding, but had no luck with that one. In fact I would like to avoid putting some alternative text and parsing it then.

Comment: `hi <sup>hi again</sup>`???

Comment: I am not using data from database in HTML page then.

Comment: How are you displaying it then? In what client will you be displaying it?

Comment: The concept of text encoding mostly applies to plain text. If you have binary data, just store it as binary.

Comment: There are [a lot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Superscripts_and_subscripts_block) of Unicode symbols for superscript digits and letters. ᴱˣᵃᵐᵖˡᵉ

Answer (score 1):

Try using an nvarchar2 data type to store in Oracle, assuming you are going to use unicode and also keep your existing character set.  For example:

```
> create table superscripts
(
  num number,
  uni nvarchar2(10)
)
table SUPERSCRIPTS created.
> insert into superscripts (num, uni) values
(
1,
'x' || SYS.utl_raw.cast_to_nvarchar2(hextoraw('00b9'))
)
1 rows inserted.
> insert into superscripts (num, uni) values
(
2,
'x' || SYS.utl_raw.cast_to_nvarchar2(hextoraw('00b2'))
)
1 rows inserted.
> insert into superscripts (num, uni) values
(
3,
'x' || SYS.utl_raw.cast_to_nvarchar2(hextoraw('00b3'))
)
1 rows inserted.
> commit
committed.
> select * from superscripts
order by num
       NUM UNI      
---------- ----------
         1 x¹         
         2 x²         
         3 x³
```

Here a good [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch6unicode.htm) that explains various approaches to using unicode.